# Como acceder al return de un Object

Tags: javascript, web, objeto

Tengo un objeto al que le hago un Object.Keys

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    let totalMonto = 
((Object.keys(groupByMarca).map(name => {
    return groupByMarca[`${name}`].map(data => {
        return {
           MontoTotal: groupByMarca[`${name}`].filter(seller=> data.Marca === seller.Marca && true).reduce((a,b) => a + b.Quantity, 0),            } },) })));
```

Cuando hago un console.log dentro de MontoTotal: me devuelve los resultados así:

```
208
48
22
 8
27
```

Todo bien. Pero necesito acceder a MontoTotal fuera del object para poder utilizarlo en mi codigo. Pero no puedo hacer un console.log fuera del return. Y si hago un console.log de totalMonto me devuelve un array con muchos objetos. Como puedo acceder a MontoTotal fuera del objeto?

Comment: Puedes adjuntar una muestra de lo que tienes en groupByMarca?

Comment: Es un array de objetos. Es muy grande no me deja poner un ejemplo el editor. Puedo subir una imagen si gustas

Comment: No es necesario que copies el array entero, pega los dos o tres primeros elementos por ejemplo

Comment: Listo. Agregué una imagen

Comment: Un par de dudas: lo que buscas es que el resultado sea un objecto en el que aparezca como key la marca y como valor la suma de Quantity? El objeto está ya agrupado por marcas o cabe la posibilidad de que dentro de BETAMOTORS? haya un elemento con `Marca!='BETAMOTORS'`?

Comment: Ya está agrupado por Marcas. Lo que necesito es la suma total de cada Marca y que eso me devuelva un array con los totales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza `reduce()` dentro del array de elementos para sumar Quantity:

```
let totalMonto = Object.keys(groupByMarca).map(name => {
   return groupByMarca[name].reduce((prev, next) => prev + next.Quantity, 0)
})
```

Comment: Perfecto me funcionó! Pero si quiero acceder solo a los valores de cada key?

Comment: Es decir, que el resultado sea un objeto en el que la key sea la marca y el valor sea el sumatorio?

Comment: Lo que me pasaste me devuelve:
 0: 296
1: 965
2: 291

SI solo quiero los valores de 0 1 y 2?

Comment: Estás seguro de que te está devolviendo un objeto? Debería ser un array de valores: [296, 965, 291, ...]

Comment: [
    296,
    965,
    291,
    142,
    76,
    91,
    47,
    72,
    17,
    7,
    4,
    48,
    22,
    8,
    27,
    1
]

Esto me devuelve

Comment: 0: 296
1: 965
2: 291
3: 142
4: 76
5: 91
6: 47
7: 72
8: 17
9: 7
10: 4
11: 48
12: 22
13: 8
14: 27
15: 1

Así en consola

Comment: Lo que quiero es que en consola solo me devuelva los valores. 296, 925, etc

Comment: Es por la representación del array, si quieres un string con los valores puedes hacer un join con `totalMonto.join(', ')`